# Salvar dados de uma Row em um array

Tags: c#, array, devexpress

Estou elaborando uma nova funcionalidade para um projeto *Winforms* em *C#*. Logo desenvolvi o seguinte método que retorna se no componente `GridControl (gvDados)` há uma linha selecionada ou não.

```
public bool RetornaSelecionado(bool Selecionado)
{
  int linhas = 0;

  foreach (int i in gvDados.GetSelectedRows())
  {
    DataRow row = gvDados.GetDataRow(i);       
    linhas++;
     //TESTE MessageBox.Show(row[0].ToString());
  }
  if(linhas > 0)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Selecionou");
    return Selecionado = true;
  }
  else
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Não selecionou");
    return Selecionado = false;
  }
}
```

O método funcionou do jeito que eu esperava. Quando seleciono um item no componente é exibido a mensagem *Selecionou* e quando não selecionado, a mensagem *Não Selecionou* é exibida. Após isto surgiu uma dúvida, como eu devo proceder para armazenar os dados de `row` em um outro `array` para que eu possa utilizar em outra validação do sistema?

Comment: o que é `gvDados`?

Comment: é o nome do meu GridControl

Comment: Debuga seu código e pega as informações em `DataRow`, ai basta atribuir no array que vc deseja!

Comment: eu fiz um ato mais amador kkkkk... Aquela linha comentada ali no código era pra saber qual item (ID, Nome, Setor) está sendo "pego" pelo `DataRow`, e é o ID...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta criar um `lits<t>` a onde T é a classe ou  o  tipo  que você deseja armazenar

Suponhamos que seja um int

```
Lits<int> meusDados =  new List<int>();

foreach (int i in gvDados.GetSelectedRows())
{
    DataRow row = gvDados.GetDataRow(i);       
    linhas++;
    meusDados.Add(Int32.Parse(row[0].ToString()));
    //TESTE MessageBox.Show(row[0].ToString());
}
```

Comment: Marcos, eu comecei testar a sua resposta aqui e já topei em um outro detalhe... Como que eu faço para chamar essa lista em um evento, por exemplo?... Sinceramente eu preciso estudar Listas pq não manjo nada :/

Comment: Como  assim  você quer chamar ela dentro de outra função ?

Comment: Bom se o evento estiver dentro  da  mesma classe você pode colocar a lista  no  escopo global ou seja, crie essa variavel Lits<int> meusDados fora da função.

Caso esteja em outra pode definir como  static

Answer (score 0):

Cria um array do tipo que você tá usando no datasource. Pra pegar o tipo é só dar um cast.

```
MeuObjeto oObjeto = (MeuObjeto)gvDados.GetRow(i);
```

Aí preenche o array com esses objetos.